# Referring to individual variables in ... with dplyr quos

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

Reading the guide to [programming with dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), I am able to refer to all `...` variables at once.  But how can I use them individually?

Here's a function that counts two variables.  It succeeds using `quos()` and `!!!`:

```
library(dplyr) # version 0.6 or higher
library(tidyr)

# counts two variables
my_fun <- function(dat, ...){

  cols <- quos(...)

  dat <- dat %>%
    count(!!!cols)

  dat

}

my_fun(mtcars, cyl, am)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>     cyl    am     n
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     4     0     3
#> 2     4     1     8
#> 3     6     0     4
#> 4     6     1     3
#> 5     8     0    12
#> 6     8     1     2
```

Now I want to `tidyr::spread` the second variable, in this case the `am` column.  When I add to my function:

```
result <- dat %>%
    tidyr::spread(!!!cols[[2]], "n", fill = 0)
```

I get:

> Error: Invalid column specification

How should I refer to just the 2nd variable of the `cols <- quos(...)` list?

Comment: What version of tidyr are you using?

Comment: tidyr 0.6.3 currently, but if it's relevant to the problem I can switch

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear whether `spread` works with `quosure` or not.  An option is to use `spread_` with strings

```html
my_fun <- function(dat, ...){

  cols <- quos(...)

  dat %>%
    select(!!! cols) %>% 
    count(!!! cols) %>%
    spread_(quo_name(cols[[2]]), "n", fill = 0)

   }

my_fun(mtcars, cyl, am)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   cyl   `0`   `1`
#* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4     3     8
#2     6     4     3
#3     8    12     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use named parameters instead. If you're relying on doing different things to different elements of the ... list it would only make sense to be explicit so it's easier to understand what each input is doing and make it easier for you to manipulate.

Comment: My actual example is more complex, users can specify either 1, 2, or 3 variables in the `...` and then it is followed by other named parameters.  And for the sake of future readers, I'd like to see how the `...` can be broken apart for referencing by position under dplyr 0.6

Comment: To me it still seems like using named parameters would be the way to go especially if you have set numbers in mind.  In my mind it's a lot easier to deal with the situation where nothing is passed into one or more of your parameters than it is to try to parse the dot list and act accordingly after the fact.

Comment: I tried it both ways and I think I agree that for my specific case, I'm better off using named parameters instead of `...`.  Thanks for the suggestion!  I'll leave the question open for now as others might come here looking for ways to parse the `...` in dplyr version >= 0.6.